# How do I map custom domains to my sites on a multisite Wordpress installation?

Tags: wordpress, dns

I just upgraded one of my many blogs to Wordpress 3.0 and I was glad to see that I now should be able to run all my blogs from a central installation.

I have the multisite stuff configured and up and running, and can create new blogs as I wish.

**My host is set up to handle wildcard subdomains, but I'd like to map my already existing, proper domains to sites instead. How do I do this?**

Redirecting the domains is not an option.

Comment: worth noting is that all the sites are on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a domain mapping plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

If you download the dev version, that will work with 3.0, I'm told:

http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/trunk/

There should be a download link at the bottom of that page.

Comment: this seems to work, i'll have to try it some more before i accept your answer

Answer (score -1):

Modrewrite is probably the answer, but without knowing more about the server and how wordpress is doing the multiple blog feature (I use it and have upgraded to 3 as well, but i haven't looked at it very closely), it's hard to give a specific answer.